# Write C# Lists of objects in CSV file

Tags: c#, list, csv

I have a C# object having 8 array elements of size 200.I need to print these arrays into a CSV file on respective labels. Data might contain string,int and double.

Ex:

```
time   time1   time2  Day  time4  time4 time5 time6 time7
1       5       9     Mon   7.0    8      9    5     NA
2
3
3
.
.
200    200    200    Sun   200    200   200   200    200
```

Oops, time1 etc are labels(Header) the data(8 lists having 200 elements) should write under these labels.
Appreciate your response !

Comment: Do you want somebody to write the program for you?

Comment: please show some code... What does not work ? any error messages/exceptions ?

Comment: And can we get you some coffee while you wait? Btw what you ask for is not a csv. Your output lacks comma's for that

Comment: Just need a hint of extracting the data and printing it in CSV. Do i need to extract each lists and use FOR loop for each lists to print the data in each column(label) ?

Comment: @CharithJ, in fact, two people have *already* written the program. Reputation, it's simply so desirable. :)

Answer (score 60):

You could write a generic function to write the objects:

```
public void WriteCSV<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string path)
{
  Type itemType = typeof(T);
  var props = itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                      .OrderBy(p => p.Name);

  using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
  {
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", props.Select(p => p.Name)));

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
      writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", props.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null))));
    }
  }
}
```

Used as:

```
var people = new List<Person> { new Person("Matt", "Abbott"), new Person("John Smith") };
WriteCSV(people, @"C:\people.csv");
```

Which *might* output:

```
Forename, Surname
Matt", Abbott"
John", Smith"
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the reply. I am finding some problems while modifying my function with this method.I will try some more options and let me know.

Comment: Changed `function` to `void`.  Thanks for this.  Saved me some time.

Comment: Well, your method won't work with large numbers,  example is that `111254006420170506` will become `111270196720170000`

Comment: I searched EVERYWHERE for how to do this in an MVC 5 C# project.  Nicely done, sir!!!

Comment: Whats a way to keep the file in memory instead of writing to disk?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming none of your data needs to have comma escaping, this should give you a general idea:

```
string[][] myArray = // your data
string[] myHeaders = // your headers
File.WriteAllText("somefile.csv", 
        string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
            new[]{myHeaders}.Concat(myArray)
            .Select(line => string.Join(",", line))));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Shall i be able to use this method for Text Writer method ? I get some errors using file

Comment: @user: why don't you try it and tell me?

Comment: I am not much familiar with string.join, i am getting overload error for the above solution given by you for file as well as for text writer methods.can you pls help me how to join the strings and print it in CSV. Thanks

Comment: @user: `string.Join` returns a string. The code above will produce the entire string that you need to output to the file, which is why I used `File.WriteAllText`. If you have a TextWriter that is ready to write, just call the `Write` method and pass it the string that is returned from the `string.Join` call above. I'm sure if you apply yourself to the problem that you'll figure it out.