# Create ReadOnly Property of CSV String vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

What is the best way to go about taking a List(Of objects) and adding a ReadOnly Property that displays a csv list of one of the Properties of the object?  Is there a good way to convert that list to a string by specifying "Name".

*Ex*

Object = New Item()
Object.ID = 1
Object.Name = "Test"
li.Add(Object)
Object = New Item()
Object.ID = 2
Object.Name = "Test 2"
li.Add(Object)
Object = New Item()
Object.ID = 3
Object.Name = "Test 3"
li.Add(Object)

I'm thinking a for each would need to be done here or is there a better way to do this?
**Return "Test, Test 2, Test 3"** from the list values
Essentially, this does what I'm wanting to do but I would like to know if there is a BETTER way to do it.:

```
Public ReadOnly Property ItemList() As String
        Get
            Dim returnvalue As String = String.Empty
            If Items.Count > 0 Then
                For Each Item In Items
                    returnvalue = returnvalue & Item.Name & ", "
                Next
                Return Left(returnvalue, returnvalue.Length - 2)
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this link to share, the solution is similar, and may need a few tweeks. The conversion from C# to VB is simple enough and can show you where to make a few changes.
[Write C# Lists of objects in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114819/write-c-sharp-lists-of-objects-in-csv-file)

However, I believe your code is fine, with the exception of how you create your csv string.
I would recommend using string builder. This way, if an item exists, you build a new line. Otherwise, you don't. This would keep your from needed to remove (left) the last inserted comma. You would also want to catch the last item in your list, and avoid the comma at the end there.

as an exmaple:

```
Dim sb As StringBuilder
--if not last item then --
sb.AppendFormat ("{0},{1}",Item.Name,",")
--else this is last item--
sb.AppendFormat ("{0},",Item.Name)
```

The link I shared is a much better solution. My example is only to build your method more reliable.

Or, if you change your list of object to an array, or list of string...

```
Dim sampleList = New List(Of String)() From { _
  "lala", _
  "lulu", _
  "lele" _
}
Dim data = String.Join(",", sampleList)
```

Comment: Looks like the stringbuilder will work.  I ended up using sb.ToString().TrimEnd(",") to remove the trailing comma in a single line.