# Accessing an Object[] inside a List

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having problems accessing an Object[] inside a List.

```
object[] datarow = null;
List<object> foo = new List<object>();
for (int i = 0; i < themonth.Length; i++) {    datarow = new object[]
{
   datarow = new object[] {themonth[i], aaa[i], bbb[i], ccc[i], ddd[i], eee[i], fff[i], ggg[i], hhh[i], iii[i] };
   foo.Add(datarow);
}
```

When I try to output the contents of the 'foo' list I'm just getting System.Object[] as output.

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.Count; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(foo.ElementAt(i));
}
```

The debugger shows me Object[] as Type - expanding it the Object[] contains the data which where putted into the 12 arrays.
The whole result would be a 10 column / 12 row list/array which I'd like to write back into a .csv File somehow.

Any Ideas how to achive that?

I tried already to create a new string[] as followed.

```
string[] test = ((IEnumerable)foo).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Output of test[i] is again a System.Object[] but without data.

Comment: `var e = (object[]) foo[i];`

Comment: What you're seeing is `object[].ToString()`, which just returns the type name. Is your question _"How to write an object array to CSV?"_, then please use the search. For example [How can I write a general Array to CSV file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666518/how-can-i-write-a-general-array-to-csv-file), [Write C# Lists of objects in CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114819/write-c-sharp-lists-of-objects-in-csv-file), and so on.

Comment: to my question is not how to write it down. I just like to know how do I access those elements in the array. I might perform some calculations based on that.

Answer (score 0):

What should `ToString()` display for an array of `object`s in your opinion?

Maybe you want to call `ToString()` of each `object`? Something like (untested)

```
var test = string.Join("\n", foo.Select(x => string.Join(" ", x.Select(y => y.ToString())));
```