# How can I write a JSON object having a list of data to a. csv file in C#?

Tags: c#, json, export-to-csv

I am trying to figure out a way, to export a JSON Object which has a list of reports where each report has a list of workflows in to a .CSV file. I looked into other related solutions but dint find them helpful. Kindly, help.

Report Class:

```
 namespace TestApp
 {
     public class report
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public DateTime? date { get; set; }
            public bool completed { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public List<worklog> worklogs { get; set; }

        }

 public class worklog
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string subcontractor { get; set; }
        public int workerCount { get; set; }
        public double hours { get; set; }
        public string workdesc { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Reportcontainer class:

```
public class reportcontainer
{
    public List<report> reports { get; set; }

    public string totalHits { get; set; }

    public void WriteReportToCSV(string Filepath)
    {
        //Write all the data here to a .csv

    }

}
```

App.cs:

```
public reportcontainer GetReports()

        {

            Console.WriteLine("Reading Reports");

            reportcontainer result = null;

            try
            {
                string url = "https://app.ragenapp.com/api/v2/reports/?startDate=2017-06-07&endDate=2017-07-07&maxResults=10000&filters=project.id:119658&filters=project.id:119654&filters=project.id:119652";

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                using (var str = new StreamReader(@"C:\projects\TestApp\App\result.json"))
                {
                    string tresult = str.ReadToEnd();

                    reportcontainer rc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<reportcontainer>(tresult);
          using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Projects\TestApp\Report_Data.csv"))
                    {

                        if (rc != null)
                        {

                            foreach (report rp in rc.reports)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(" Reading: " + rp.id + "," + rp.status + "," + rp.completed + "," + rp.date);

                            }

                                foreach (worklog wl in rc.reports.SelectMany(r => r.worklogs))

                                {

                                    Console.WriteLine(" Reading: " + wl.id + "," + wl.hours + "," + wl.workerCount + "," + wl.workdesc);

                                }



                            foreach (report rep in rc.reports)

                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(" Reading:" + "," + rep.id + "," + rep.status + "," + rep.completed + "," + rep.date);

                            }

                                foreach (worklog wl in rc.reports.SelectMany(r => r.worklogs))

                                {

                                    sw.WriteLine(" Reading:" + wl.id + "," + wl.hours + "," + wl.workerCount + "," + wl.workdesc);

                                }


                        }
                    }
               }
            }
                      // }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }

            return result;  
 }
```

Comment: A csv is not really suitable to represent a hierarchical data structure. What would your expected output look like?

Comment: Your data is hierarchical and already in a pretty great format for that type of data (JSON).

Comment: Just to print out a list of worklogs under each report. If not, could you suggest me a better way out? @Rotem

Comment: As @maccettura said, JSON is already the ideal textual format for representing this data. Explain what you're trying to achieve by using CSV, which is most suitable for representing data as a *table*.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Well, I have been tasked to export the reports/ worklogs data in to individual csv tables. As it is in a hierarchical structure, could you suggest me a way to export the report and worklog data in to a CSV file? @Rotem

Comment: You can either export each report to its own file, or you can write them all out to a single file, where some rows represent a report and some rows represent a worklog. Either way, please be more specific about what you're having trouble with. Is it writing to a file in general? Is it iterating over the JSON data? There are countless questions dealing with both.

Comment: I apologize.As you said I would like to write them all in to a single file, where some rows represent a report and some rows represent a worklog. How can I use my WriteReportToCSV() function to do this job?@Rotem

Comment: Thank you for your help @Rotem. I am able to get list of report and worklog data in to a csv by updating App.cs code. Could you suggest me another way to do the same job using the function (WriteReportToCSV()) defined in the Reportcontainer class ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write C# Lists of objects in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114819/write-c-sharp-lists-of-objects-in-csv-file)

Comment: post sample expected csv output.